# Analyzing dependency of dependency as a pom

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Let’s assume we create a project which is a kind of library project(a project aggregates dependencies).

```
    <project>
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis2-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
          <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
          <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
          <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
          <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
          <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Another project is using the library project as a dependency.

```
    <project>
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-axis2-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
          <artifactId>axis2-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <type>pom<type>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

I think this use-case assumes that **my-axis2-client** uses the dependencies in **axis2-client** as direct dependency.
So it means I can use, let’s say, org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient(in axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar) class in my-axis2-client.
However, when I run `mvn dependency:anlyze`, it generates the following result.

```
    [WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
    [WARNING]     org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernal:jar:1.6.2:compile
    [WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
    [WARNING]     compackt:axis2-client:pom:1.0.0:compile
```

I don’t think this is a valid warning. 
Please let me know if there is any way to analyze dependencies this case.

Comment: Maybe the dependency plugin is not smart enough to handle the pom dependency and its transitive dependencies properly. It seems to me your dependencies are correct, but you should store the '1.6.2' version in a property, e.g. `axis2.version`, instead of repeating the number for each dependency.

Comment: @gjoranv I agree with your idea. Especially, "Maybe the dependency plugin is not smart enough" part. Maybe I need to suggest analyze plugin project to improve for this use case. Than you for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your construction, the resulting dependencies are *transitive*, not direct. You depend on a POM, which itself depends on the jars.

Comment: You are right. However, what I wonder is a validity of result of analyze plugin. I think the intention of maven users is using this type of dependency(pom type dependency) as a library. So, the dependency plugin should not report the use of axis2 dependency as WARNING. It seems it's an issue of the plugin(as @gjoranv mentioned). Thank you for the comment.